# jQuery: c.replace is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Actually, i got "c.replace is not a function" while i was trying to use .animate() ..i don't understand whats causing this error.

jQuery Code

```
$(function() {
$(".order-verify-button .sms-button").on('click', function(){
    $( ".order-verify-sms,.cod-order-verify,.order-detail-box" ).animate({ height: 'hide', opacity: 'hide' }, '100');   
    $("#first-sms-button").css('display','none');
    $( ".verification-apply-code" ).animate({ height: 'show', opacity: 'show' }, '100'); 
    $("#button_verify_sms").css('display','block');
});
    var $options = $('.verification-apply-code .verification-method .item');
    $options.click(function(e){
        var $current = $(this);
        e.preventDefault()
        e.stopPropagation()
        $options.removeClass('on')
        $current.addClass('on')
        $('input', $current).prop('checked', true)
    })
```

});

Error

```
jquery-1.7.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: c.replace is not a function
at bC (jquery-1.7.min.js:4)
at Function.css (jquery-1.7.min.js:4)
at fx.cur (jquery-1.7.min.js:4)
at HTMLDivElement.g (jquery-1.7.min.js:4)
at Function.dequeue (jquery-1.7.min.js:2)
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (jquery-1.7.min.js:2)
at Function.each (jquery-1.7.min.js:2)
at init.each (jquery-1.7.min.js:2)
at init.queue (jquery-1.7.min.js:2)
at init.animate (jquery-1.7.min.js:4)
```

Comment: Can you post a runnable [MCVE] so we can reproduce the problem ourselves? What actual line does the error occur at in your code?

Comment: There is no `c.replace` anywhere in your code.

Comment: Yes that is the issue if i remove this part .animate({ height: 'hide', opacity: 'hide' }, '100'); there is no error so i am sure the error is related to the animate function

Comment: Neither `height: hide` nor `opacity: hide` is valid CSS.